# Два разных параллельных потока в Activity разные по времени

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

уважаемые!
В AsyncTask получаю JSON данные по REST с сервера, обрабатываю с помощью Jackson и отправляю это в ListView.

Проблема в том, что мне нужно получать данные по двум разным url-запросам(с разными параметрами AsynсTask), причем ответ по первому запросу приходит через 1 сек, а по второму запросу может доходить до - 20 сек (специфика поиска данных на бэкенде)

1. Как можно запустить параллельно два разных таких потока и выводить результат по мере получения данных в ListView? И должны ли быть разные ListView для каждого потока?
2. Так как время на поиск данных происходит на бэкенде, каким образом можно отловить это время и завернуть в ProgressBar? Банальные способы установки прогресса в методы onPreExecute() и onPostExecute() ничего не дают - прогресс появляется на доли секунды уже непосредственно перед отображением результата.

Answer (score 0):

1) Ну, раз уже работает с AsycTask, то можно сделать два AsycTask =) Вроде никаких подводных камней с несложной, как я понимаю, программой вы не встретите. Список может быть один, но тогда вам нужно в нем реализовать логику реакции на завершения каждого из тасков, причем так, чтоб они могли завершится в любом порядке/могли не все завершится. Как именно это делать - зависит от самих данных и того как вы хотите их отображать. Хотите более конкретного совета - ответьте на эти вопросы

2) Зависит, конечно, от бэкэнда и способа сбора ответа, но почти наверняка в на самом бэкэнде не сможете просчитать процент выполнения, не то что передать его клиенту. Если это один большущий запрос к бд - точно не выйдет, если огромное количество маленьких - можете попробовать, например, слать запросы пачками, а не одним, и отображать в процентах сколько запросов уже выполнено. Но это костылирование. ЛУчше просто повесьте круглый прогрессБар, юзеры к ним вполне привыкли

Comment: 1. Да, проблемы нет сделать два таска, но после ответа сервера, а именно после второго длительного запроса приложение крашится :( При этом использую два разных ListView
2. Я согласен на круглый прогрессБар, но отрабатывает он очень странно - за доли секунды до отображения данных появляется и пропадает

Comment: @SeregaS если крашится показывай `logcat`

Comment: Если прогрессбар пропадает - значит что-то работает не так, как должно. Об этом уже придется спрашивать в отдельном вопросе. Если завершение второго таска роняет приложение - это рпоблема не таска, а приложения. Разбираться надо, а не отказываться после первой неудачи =)

Comment: Ребят, решено переделать вывод результата тасков в новое активити. Через интент отправляю параметр для таска во второую активити и два параллельных запроса запускаю уже в ней. Теперь все прекрасно работает - таски отрабатывают вместе, хотя меня и последовательный вариант устраивает - в onPostExecute запускаю второй поток.

Comment: НО теперь проблема в другом - при поиске данных(кнопка на первой активити) должен быть переход на вторую активити, однако во время запроса появляется просто черный экран, не принадлежащий ни одной активити, только после того как данные приходят от сервера, появлется вторая активити с результатами. Я бы рад на это время повесить прогрессБар, но он никак хочет дружить с моими тасками..(

Comment: Имхо, подход ооочень неправильный. У вас два параллельных запроса, которые друг от друга не зависят, зачем вы запускаете второй в onPostExecute первого? Запускайте оба одновременно, они для того и нужны =) Про черный экран - есть идеи как вы его получили, но это уже другой вопрос, создайте его